# Read string arrays from file

Tags: java, arrays, string, read-write

I have this code:

```
public static void write() throws IOException{
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream("ips.txt")
        );
    for ( int  i = 0; i < Main.ipList.length; i++){
        out.writeObject(ipList[i]);
    }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
}
```

Which writes the string array to a text file:

```
static String[] ipList = {"127.0.0.1", "173.57.51.111"};
```

I was wondering how it would be possible to read the text file and edit the ipList with the new ips.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write `String` objects to a file, it's better to use a `FileWriter` instead of an `ObjectOutputStream`. Similarly, use a `FileReader` to read from the file. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html for how to use these `Reader` objects.

`ObjectOutputStream` is usually suitable for writing more complex objects that implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface.

Here's an example:

```
BufferedReader inputStream = null;
List<String> ipList = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ips.txt"));
    String l;
    while ((l = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
       ipList.add(l);
    }
} finally {
    if (inputStream != null) {
        inputStream.close();
    }  
}

// get an array from the ArrayList
ipArray = ipList.toArray(new String[ipList.size()]);
```

Comment: Ok I have it saving as a FIleWriter now but I cant get FileReader to load the string array.

Comment: Here is my new code. How do I make 'in' the loaded array?  

static String[] ipList = {"127.0.0.1", "173.57.51.111"};

 public static void read(){
  try {
   FileReader in = new FileReader("ips.txt");
   
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  
 }
 
 public static void write() throws IOException{
  FileWriter out = new FileWriter("ips.txt");
  for ( int  i = 0; i < Main.ipList.length; i++){
   out.write(ipList[i]);
  }
   out.flush();
   out.close();
 }

Comment: @randomnessthatsfunny Please see my edit. And add your update in your answer, not in a comment.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this

```
package a;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class A {

    static String[] ipList = { "127.0.0.1", "173.57.51.111" };

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            write();
            update();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

        Arrays.asList(ipList).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    // Your method
    public static void write() throws IOException {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("ips.txt"));
        for (int i = 0; i < A.ipList.length; i++) {
            out.writeObject(ipList[i]);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

    public static void update() throws IOException {

        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(".", "newIps.txt"));

        List<String> newIps = new ArrayList<>();
        newIps.addAll(Arrays.asList(ipList));
        newIps.addAll(lines);
        ipList = newIps.toArray(ipList);
    }
}
```

The content of the `newIps.txt` file is

```
0.0.0.0
192.168.1.1
```

The output of the program is

```
127.0.0.1
173.57.51.111
0.0.0.0
192.168.1.1
```

Note that `Arrays.asList(ipList)` returns a bridge list over the array (any changes to the list will be visible for array), so we do a putAll